# Blind actuator end positions

Tags: actuators

Looking at a new electronic shading system for my flat I was wondering how blind actuators generally work. I know they switch between the two phases (L -> down, L' -> up) depending on the 2-button switch.

But how do they know the end positions of the blinds?

Some motors detect the load on the drive shaft and "stop", but when I press the button I would still supply voltage to the motor? Or does the actuator detect that the motors stopped and internally also opens a switch so that no more power is supplied?

Comment: you are making an incorrect assumption that all blinds are built the same way

Comment: Not sure about blinds, but the usual way to solve this is with limit switches. Once the blind is wound as far one way as you like, the movement of the blind mechanically contacts the limit switch, cutting power to the motor. The motor is free to travel in the opposite direction until it's stopped by a similar limit switch at the other extreme.